# .NET Core dependency injection error : "Unable to resolve service for type 'AspNetCoreWebAPI.Data.IBookRepository'"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to learn ASP.NET Core Web API using ADO.NET in VS Code and I end up with an error that I don't understand.

In `startup`, I add two scoped services:

```
using System.Net;
using AspNetCoreWebAPI.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using AspNetCoreWebAPI.Helpers;

namespace AspNetCoreWebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IBookRepository, BookRepository>();           
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `BooksController`:

```
public class BooksController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBookRepository _repo;

    public BooksController(IBookRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    } 

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        MyBooks = await _repo.GetBooks();
        return Ok(MyBooks);
    }
}
```

programer.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/webapi2.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)",
                "uriFormat": "%s/weatherforecast"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/webapi2.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/webapi2.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "${workspaceFolder}/webapi2.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Ibookrepository

```
public interface IBookRepository
    {
           Task<List<Books>> GetBooks();
    }
```

Bookrepository

```
public class BookRepository:IBookRepository
    {
        public async Task<List<Books>> GetBooks()
        {
            List<Books> MyBooks = new List<Books>();

            DataConnection dc = new DataConnection();
            var task = new Task(() =>
            {
                DataTable dt = dc.GetData("SELECT * FROM dbo.Books");

                // POPULATE THE LIST WITH DATA.
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    MyBooks.Add(new Books
                    {
                        BookID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["BookID"]),
                        BookName = dr["BookName"].ToString(),
                        Category = dr["Category"].ToString(),
                        Price = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Price"])
                    });
                }
            });
            task.Start();
            await task;
            return MyBooks;

        }
        
    }
```

Whenever I call a method on the `BooksController`, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AspNetCoreWebAPI.Data.IBookRepository' while attempting to activate 'AspNetCoreWebAPI.Controllers.BooksController'

Comment: Hi , the error message saying that your application is trying to create an instance of `BooksController` but it doesn't know how to create an instance of `IBookRepository` to pass into the constructor. But from the code you shared , There is nothing wrong with your dependency injection . can you prodive the whole `startup.cs` ?

Comment: Hi Xinran Shen
  Thanks for the comment i have edited the question adding full startup.cs

Comment: Hi , I don't find any error in dependency injection from the code you shared , I guess that some settings in your code may affect dependency injection ，You can share your whole project if you wiliing . By the way , why there is no `services.AddControllers()` in `startup` ?

Comment: Your code is fine. the is a problem in your dependency injection. can you share your repository interface and implementation?

Comment: Hi , Which version of .net are you using ？ The code in `programer.cs` is the style of .Net 6 , But .net 6 don't have the `Startup` , I am very confused about this

Comment: dont know which version i first used for this code i need to reinstall os and downloaded new version then created new project and copy paste old code to new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this code in your `programer.cs` :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IBookRepository, BookRepository>();
//.......
```

Comment: Thanks it wroked.i didn't know sartup class not in .net core 6. what to do if i want startup class to use

Comment: you can read this document about the new in asp .net core 6: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-6.0?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Refer to:[How to accept as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks.